# How to load XRegExp in Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, xregexp

I want to use XRegExp library in an Angular2 application written in TypeScript.

I have installed XRegExp as a node.js module.

How do I get `var unicodeWord = XRegExp("^\\pL+$");` to work in a component method?

(How do I reference the JS library in TypeScript? How do I load the node.js module in angular?)

**UPDATE**

typings.json:

```
{
    "ambientDependencies": {
        "es6-shim": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts#6697d6f7dadbf5773cb40ecda35a76027e0783b2",
        "jasmine": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts#d594ef506d1efe2fea15f8f39099d19b39436b71",
        "xregexp": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/xregexp/xregexp.d.ts"
    }
}
```

`<head>` tag in my index.html:

```
<head>
    <title>Amadeus</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
        System.config({
            paths: {
                xregexp: 'node_modules/xregexp/src/xregexp.js'
            },
            packages: {        
                angular_components: {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });

        System.import('angular_components/ignition')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

</head>
```

ignition.ts:

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AmadeusComponent} from './amadeus/amadeus.component'

bootstrap(AmadeusComponent);
```

amadeus.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {XRegExp} from 'xregexp';

@Component({
    selector: 'amadeus',
    templateUrl: 'angular_components/amadeus/amadeus.component.ahtml'
})

export class AmadeusComponent {

    constructor(){
        console.log(XRegExp); // undefined
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you need to include its [typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/demo-typescript-node-minimal/blob/master/typings/xregexp/xregexp.d.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the following way:

In your package.json add 'typings' as dev dependency, and (optionally) postinstall action:

```
"devDependencies": 
{
    "typings": "latest"
},
"scripts": 
{
    "postinstall": "typings install --save"
}
```

Add typings.json file with the following content to your root folder:

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "xregexp": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/xregexp/xregexp.d.ts"
  }
}
```

Then navigate in console to your project root (where your package.json, tsconfig.json, etc are) and run

> npm install

this will get you typescript definitions for xregexp library.

Do not forget to exclude browser (or main) definitions using exclude section in your tsconfig file like this:

```
{ 
    "compilerOptions": { 
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true, 
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "module": "commonjs", 
        "target": "es6",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "bin",
        "declaration": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/browser.d.ts",
        "typings/browser/**"
    ]
}
```

In your systemjs config:

```
    System.config({
        paths: {
            xregexp: 'path/to/xregexp.js'
        }             
    });

    System.defaultJSExtensions = true;
```

Then to use it:

```
import XRegExp = require('xregexp');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: And how do I load XRegExp? <script> tags in my html? System.import?

Comment: SystemJS or requireJS will do the job just fine according to the installation guide: https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp/blob/master/README.md#installation-and-usage

Comment: Please check my last update. You have to setup xregexp package in systemjs like you did for angular_components. Or like I have shown with 'path' option.

Comment: Now there are no console errors, but XRegExp is undefined.

Comment: Try to reference xregexp-all.js in paths. Not xregexp.js

Comment: Same thing. I debugged the transpiled js file of my component. In this line console.log(xregexp_1.XRegExp); xregexp_1 references XRegExp, not xregexp_1.XRegExp

Comment: It should be imported using: import XRegExp = require('xregexp');