# How to implement XRegExp in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, xregexp

So I've been trying to implement a `p{L}` pattern in my Angular project without any success. I have tried this [`npm package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-regex-pl) and set my variable as follows (in many ways):

```
nameRegex = new RegExp(/^[${pL}]+$/);
```

and then I followed the answers at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36071164/how-to-load-xregexp-in-angular2) but `import XRegExp = require('xregexp');` does not work on TypeScript and I wouldn't know how to set my variable. Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: require is part of CommonJS - See here https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/what-is-require/ Webpack can use that see here https://webpack.js.org/concepts/modules/#what-is-a-webpack-module - what version of webpack are you using 1 or 2?

Answer (score 1):

I import this way:

```
import XRegExp from 'xregexp';
```

And add this line

```
compilerOptions: {"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true}
```

to tsconfig.json file.

This way working perfectly from my side with Angular 11.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I do it.  though the latest version of the cli is causing this to have an error in IE 11

```
import * as XRegExp from 'xregexp';
```